# Agregar propiedad si en el objeto no se encuentra esa propiedad Javascript

Tags: javascript

La funcion llamada 'agregaPropiedad' recibe como argumento un array llamado 'amigos' que contiene
en cada posición del arreglo un objeto que puede tener como propiedades 'nombre' o 'edad'. También
recibe un string llamado 'propiedad'.
Esta funcion debe agregar la propiedad 'propiedad' y setearla en null a aquellos objetos dentro de 'amigos' que no tengan esa propiedad
Debe devolver el array 'amigos' modificado.
Nota: Si el objeto dentro de 'amigos' tiene esa 'propiedad' no modificarla.
Ej:
var amigos = [{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];
agregaPropiedad(amigos, 'edad') debe devolver [{ nombre: 'toni', edad: null } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }]

Me gustaría que me ayuden a encontrar porque no funciona mi solución, ya se que se puede hacer con for each y el metodo hasownproperty.

Lo que pense fue en realizar esto:

```
function agregaPropiedad(amigos, propiedad) {
for (var i = 0; i < amigos.length; i++) {
      if (amigos[i][propiedad] !== propiedad) {
         amigos[i][propiedad] = null;
      }
    }
    return amigos;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Antes de ver el código tenga en cuenta que los arreglos y objetos en javascript se pasan por referencia a las funciones, esto quiere decir que la variable original se verá modificada.
Si desea mantener el arreglo original procure usar algun lifehack como `let copia = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(amigos))` para crear una copia de su variable y no modificar el contenido original.

Teniendo presente lo anterior, la función cuenta con un array donde se agregarán las propiedades para inicializar el objeto, para cada objeto recorre todas las propiedades que debiera tener y se pregunta si existe (no es `undefined`), si no existe se agregará con un `null`.

```js
var amigos = [{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];


function agregarPropiedad(amigos) {
  amigos.forEach(amigo => {
    let propiedades = ['nombre', 'edad'] 
    propiedades.forEach((propiedad) => {
      if(typeof(amigo[propiedad]) == 'undefined'){
        amigo[propiedad] = null
      }
    })
    return amigo
  })
}

agregarPropiedad(amigos)
console.log(amigos)
```

**Buena practica** (Este apartado puede ser considerado una opinión)

Agregar nuevas propiedades en tiempo de ejecución dificulta la lectura y la mantenibilidad del código a futuro. Lo ideal es siempre saber lo que se va a encontrar en un objeto de manera explicita sin tener que realizar un desgaste cognitivo mayor, el código debe explicarse por su propia cuenta.

En otras palabras, tu amigo debiera ser una *clase/estructura de datos* que defina su contenido.

```js
class Amigo {
  nombre = null
  edad = null
}

amigos = []

amigo = new Amigo()
amigo.nombre = 'Hola césarito'

amigos.push(amigo)

amigo = new Amigo()
amigo.edad = 26

amigos.push(amigo)

console.log(amigos)
```

Si te fijas, a diferencia del primer elemento, se entiende la entidad que estás creando y en cualquier momento se puede ir a la declaración para ver todas las propiedades que tiene un "Amigo".

**Actualización**

Tu código no funciona porque el if no hace lo que tu crees que hace y lo podemos ver agregando un simple `console.log` para ver los valores que se están comparando. En este caso, estás comparando el valor de la propiedad (en caso que exista, `undefined` si no existe) con el nombre de la propiedad.

Tu if en palabras es: Si el valor de la propiedad es diferente al nombre de la propiedad y son el mismo tipo de dato, entonces cambia el valor de la propiedad a null.

EJ

```js
var amigos = [{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];

function agregaPropiedad(amigos, propiedad) {
  for (var i = 0; i < amigos.length; i++) {
      console.log(`Iteración ${i} ______________________`)
      console.log("Valores en comparación: ", amigos[i][propiedad], " <- vs -> ", propiedad)
      if (amigos[i][propiedad] !== propiedad) {
        console.log("Cumple la condición !== , se procede a reemplazar el valor por null o crear la propiedad si no existe y establecerla en null")
         amigos[i][propiedad] = null;
      }
    }
  return amigos;
}


result = agregaPropiedad(amigos, 'edad')

console.log(result)
```

La solución es básicamente modificar tu condicional, como se muestra más abajo. Las propiedades que no existen son de tipo `undefined` por lo cual simplemente tienes que validar si es de ese tipo para proceder a inicializarla.

```js
var amigos = [{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];

function agregaPropiedad(amigos, propiedad) {
  for (var i = 0; i < amigos.length; i++) {
      if (amigos[i][propiedad] === undefined) {
         amigos[i][propiedad] = null;
      }
    }
  return amigos;
}

agregaPropiedad(amigos, 'edad')
console.log(amigos)
```

Comment: Hola cesar, muchas gracias por tu amplia respuesta y tomarte el tiempo de explicarme tu solución. Quería consultarte si hay alguna forma de resolver el ejercicio sin usar métodos como for each y typeoff, similar a lo que escribí yo, quisiera saber saber porque no funciona el mío.

Comment: Hola @Cristian , He actualizado la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una modificacion de tu codigo que servira para el proposito que necesitas:

```js
function agregaPropiedad(amigos, propiedad) {
  
  for(let amigo of amigos)
  {
    if(!amigo.hasOwnProperty(propiedad))
    {
      amigo[propiedad] = null;
    }
  }
  
  return amigos;
  
}

const amigos = agregaPropiedad([{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }], "edad");

console.log(amigos);
```

Recordemos que hay 2 formas de acceder a las propiedades de un objeto, esta:

```
object.propiedad;
```

O tambien:

```
object["propiedad"];
```

Ambos dan el mismo resultado, podemos aprovecharnos de este concepto para entonces acceder a las propiedades de la forma en la que necesitemos.

Entonces recorremos el arreglo de amigos con un `for of`:

```
for(let amigo of amigos)
```

Por cada amigo buscamos si no tiene una propiedad que coincida con la que buscamos:

```
if(!amigo.hasOwnProperty(propiedad))
```

Si la condicion es verdadera entonces asumimos que la propiedad que estamos buscando no existe, por lo tanto se la añadimos:

```
amigo[propiedad] = null;
```

Por ultimo retornamos el resultado del arreglo modificado:

```
return amigos;
```

Comment: El OP dice en su pregunta: *Me gustaría que me ayuden a encontrar porque no funciona mi solución, ya se que se puede hacer con for each y el metodo hasownproperty*, por lo cual entiendo yo que **no desea** utilizar `hasOwnProperty`. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema en tu intento se encuentra en la siguiente comparación:

```js
if (amigos[i][propiedad] !== propiedad) { ... }
```

Tal como está escrita esta sentencia indica que se compara el valor de `amigos[i][propiedad]` con el valor de `propiedad`.

En realidad lo que tu deseas es comparar el nombre de la propiedad del objeto (el nombre de la clave o atributo) con el valor almacenado en la variable `propiedad`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Existen diversas formas de verificar si un objeto contiene una propiedad con un nombre específico. Una de las más conocidas es [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), que devuelve un booleano que indica si el objeto analizado contiene o no la propiedad especificada.

Pero en tu pregunta planteas que no deseas usar dicho método, por lo cual hay que usar otra forma de establecer si la propiedad existe en el objeto.

**Usando `Object.keys()`**

Una forma de hacerlo es obtener todos los nombres de los atributos del objeto en una lista o Array. Para esto nos podemos apoyar en el método [`keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) del objeto global [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/), que nos devuelve un Array con los nombres de todos los atributos del objeto que vamos a analizar. Una vez que tenemos la lista de los nombres de atributos, es fácil verificar si el nombre que buscamos está en dicha lista, usando el método [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) que devuelve un booleano indicando la existencia o no del nombre en la lista.

Por ejemplo:

```js
if(!Object.keys(amigos[i]).includes(propiedad)) { ... }
```

Como se aprecia, estoy usando una negación `!` y la sentencia se lee: *si entre los nombres de las claves del elemento `i` de amigos **no** se incluye `propiedad`...*

El código completo funcionando podría verse así:

```js
function agregaPropiedad(amigos, propiedad) {
  for (let i = 0; i < amigos.length; i++) {
    if(!Object.keys(amigos[i]).includes(propiedad)) {
      amigos[i][propiedad] = null;
    }
  }
  return amigos;
}

const amigos = agregaPropiedad([{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }], "edad");

console.log(amigos);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Usando un bucle `for ... in`**

Otra forma de verificar si una propiedad existe dentro de un objeto, es iterando sobre las mismas usando el bucle [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). De esta manera es sencillo luego comparar el nombre del atributo con el valor que estamos buscando. Por ejemplo:

```js
for (let prop in amigos[i]) {
  if(prop === propiedad) { ... }
}
```

En el bucle, comparamos el nombre de la propiedad del objeto que estamos iterando con el valor de la variable `propiedad`. En este caso en particular, podemos usar una bandera (`flag`) que nos indique si el nombre buscado ha sido encontrado. Esta bandera o `flag` es una variable de tipo booleana.
Por ejemplo:

```js
let existePropiedad = false;
for (let prop in amigos[i]) {
  if(prop === propiedad) {
    existePropiedad = true;
    break;
  }
}
if(!existePropiedad) { ... }
```

Como se aprecia, si la propiedad existe en el objeto, establecemos el valor de la bandera a `true` y dejamos de iterar mediante la sentencia `break` (ya no es necesario seguir iterando porque hemos hallado la propiedad buscada). Finalmente, evaluamos el valor de la bandera y realizamos la acción adecuada.

Un ejemplo de lo anterior podría ser:

```js
function agregaPropiedad(amigos, propiedad) {
  for (let i = 0; i < amigos.length; i++) {
    let existePropiedad = false;
    for(let prop in amigos[i]) {
      if(prop === propiedad) {
        existePropiedad = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!existePropiedad) {
      amigos[i][propiedad] = null;
    }
  }
  return amigos;
}

const amigos = agregaPropiedad([{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }], "edad");

console.log(amigos);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como puedes observar, en ambos casos se retorna el resultado esperado, sin usar `forEach` ni `hasOwnProperty`. Espero que esto te aclare la duda y te ayude a resolver el problema.